# Have spapp file read assets from SiteAssets folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, new-experience

After going through the tutorials on SPFX, they show you how to use gulp to deploy your javascript/css to a Storage account and CDN.

However, when I'm creating solutions for clients, I'll store my code in /SiteAssets. Then, I'll a CEWP and link it to a txt file. This makes updating the code easy since all I have to do is add in a tag to pull in the JS/CSS from that folder in SiteAssets.  This keeps the potential development barriers low since the rights needed are at a minimum and typically do things via JSOM. From a cost perspective, there's no CDN to worry about setting up/paying for since we're using an already existing folder to store/serve our content.

With SPFX, we require access to the App Catalog, and then deploy that app out. This means I'll need a lot higher access, which can cause a delay in some projects, not to mention if I have to update the app. My goal is to put together some decent proof-of-concepts for our company using the new experience.

Is there a way I can take the SPFX .webpart file (in /sharepoint/solution/debug) and upload it to the site using Import Webpart and have that link to my content in SiteAssets? I looked at [Add HelloWorld web part to classic page](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page) but could not get it to work on a classic page.

Comment: HI Breant, I am new to spfx and want to generate an client side web part which will deploy master page and page layouts in sharepoint online. can you shed some light in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to bypass needing to register your solution in the app catalog?  If so - then no, there is no current way to do that.  The .webpart file will have a reference to the component ID in the app catalog, and that is how the code is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, thats essentially what I was doing. So I could treat it like I would a content editor and load my code in SiteAssets and have the spapp refer to it in that location.  

I sorta realized this watching the tutorial of how the new webparts are loaded into the classic experience. (I was doing it wrong).

Comment: Can you tell me if it's possible to have the spapp file still refer to js/css files at a site level?  

This way I can deploy the spapp to their App Catalog and still deliver a custom experience for them?

Comment: So, kind of.  You can certainly refer to js files living wherever, however it will be difficult to reference your files if your app gets loaded into a different site collection, subweb, etc.